# Three.js - Create flat circle with texture..?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Can I create a flat circle with texture?
The only thing I could think of was THREE.CylinderGeometry with radius=1...
But not only the texture is not placed right,it rendered really slow :-(

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `sprite` is what you're looking for: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/Sprite.js

Comment: Is it rendered with CanvasRender() as well? Can you give some example link? Thanks...

Comment: I don't know, check out example here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_sprites.html and source here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_sprites.html

Comment: Yes,as I thought...It's capable only in webGL rendering :-(

Comment: @BorisD just because the example uses the WebGLRenderer it doesn't mean it's webgl only. Particles do work quite well with the Canvas Renderer as you can see in the [examples that come with three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_particles_random.html)

Comment: Hello there...George Profenza, again thank you for your answers! Yeap, I already seen this example and managed to create those circles. The question is how to add a texture in this code...It's not a normal use of "THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture"